# TypeError: 'module' object is not callable Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hello i tried run the run.py but i got an error message!

Run.py

```
from modules import HTTPHeaders
site = "https://google.com"
HTTPHeaders(site, _verbose=True)
```

HTTPHeaders.py

```
import dns
import dns.resolver
def HTTPHeaders(site, _verbose=None):
if _verbose != None:
    try:
        r = http.request('GET', "http://"+site)
    except:
        pass

    if (r.status == 200):
        print("HTTP/1.1 200 OK")
    else:
        print(r.status)
    try:
        print("Content-Type : "+r.headers['Content-Type'])
    except:
        pass
    try:
        print("Server : "+r.headers['Server'])
    except:
        pass
    try:
        print("Set-Cookie : "+r.headers['Set-Cookie'])
    except:
        pass
```

My error :

```
    TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

How can i fix this error ? Thank you :)

Comment: As the error very clearly indicates, you are trying to call the imported module which is not possible. What you intended to do, is call the **function** with the same name from within this module: `HTTPHeaders.HTTPHeaders(site, _verbose=True)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```py
from modules import HTTPHeaders
HTTPHeaders.HTTPHeaders(...)
```

You imported the module itself, so you have to access the function using the dot notation.

Alternatively import the function like this:

```py
from modules.HTTPHeaders import HTTPHeaders
HTTPHeaders(...)
```

Comment: Sorry, I changed the text of the answer.

Comment: Noticed, now it's very correct :)